# New module doesn't create table

Tags: installation, table, installer

My new module cant create a table while i clean *core_resource* table.
Here is my *config.xml* file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Alkos_Flexibleimport>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Alkos_Flexibleimport>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <flexibleimport>
                <class>Alkos_Flexibleimport_Block</class>
            </flexibleimport>
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <flexibleimport>
                <class>Alkos_Flexibleimport_Helper</class>
            </flexibleimport>
        </helpers>
        <models>
            <flexibleimport>
                <class>Alkos_Flexibleimport_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>flexibleimport_resource</resourceModel>
            </flexibleimport>
            <flexibleimport_resource>
                <class>Alkos_Flexibleimport_Model_Resource</class>
                <entities>
                    <flexibleimport>
                        <table>alkos_flexibleimport</table>
                    </flexibleimport>
                </entities>
            </flexibleimport_resource>
        </models>


        <resources>
            <alkos_flexibleimport_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Alkos_Flexibleimport</module>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </alkos_flexibleimport_setup>
            <alkos_flexibleimport_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </alkos_flexibleimport_write>
            <alkos_flexibleimport_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </alkos_flexibleimport_read>
        </resources>
    </global>
    <adminhtml>
        <translate>
            <modules>
                <alkos_flexibleimport>
                    <files>
                        <default>Alkos_Flexibleimport.csv</default>
                    </files>
                </alkos_flexibleimport>
            </modules>
        </translate>

        <layout>
            <updates>
                <alkos_flexibleimport>
                    <file>alkos/flexibleimport.xml</file>
                </alkos_flexibleimport>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </adminhtml>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <alkos_flexibleimport before="Mage_Adminhtml">Alkos_Flexibleimport_Adminhtml</alkos_flexibleimport>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
</config>
```

Model file *Alkos/Flexibleimport/Model/Flexibleimport.php*

```
class Alkos_Flexibleimport_Model_Resource_Flexibleimport extends Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Abstract {
protected function _construct ()
{
    $this->_init('flexibleimport/flexibleimport', 'flexibleimport_id');
}
```

}

Resorce file *Alkos/Flexibleimport/Model/Resource/Flexibleimport.php*

```
class Alkos_Flexibleimport_Model_Resource_Flexibleimport extends Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Abstract {
protected function _construct ()
{
    $this->_init('flexibleimport/flexibleimport', 'flexibleimport_id');
}
```

}

Collection file *Alkos/Flexibleimport/Model/Resource/Flexibleimport/Collection.php*

```
  class Alkos_Flexibleimport_Model_Resource_Flexibleimport_Collection extends Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Collection_Abstract
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('flexibleimport/flexibleimport');
    }
}
```

Isntaller *Alkos/Flexibleimport/sql/alkos_flexibleimport_setup/mysql4-install-1.0.0.php*

```
    $installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

$installer->run("
CREATE TABLE `{$this->getTable('flexibleimport/flexibleimport')}` (
    `flexibleimport_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `profile` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `type` enum('pages','blocks') NOT NULL,
    `action` enum('import','export') NOT NULL,
    `format` enum('csv','xml') NOT NULL,
    `directory` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (`flexibleimport_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
");

$installer->endSetup();
```

Sorry for wrong insert, i cannot insert it correctly

Comment: i dont see any errors in magento while trying to install script, new table is not appear in database, but in core_resource it adding successfully

Comment: I tried the same code and I was able to create the table. Can you manually create a table to database with your username and password?

Comment: i have another custom module, it creates the table successfully.  I thought i mixed up somwthing with namespaces

Comment: Can you see a row with code `alkos_flexibleimport_setup` in `core_resource` table with version and data_version set to 1.0.0?

Comment: Have you declared your module in `app/etc/modules/` and also clear your Magento cache?